# Using Sed or Grep or Awk or print for get the specific data

Tags: bash, printing, awk, sed, grep

i am experiencing issues with getting the right parse format from my log.

here is sample:

```
<user type="A" name="user1" prod="" trunk="data1(none)" trunk_data="tr1" IE="0" thid="id_0x1c682a0">
```

I need to get this output:

```
user1 data1(none)
```

what is the best way to get the data format i need? Everytime the data i need is in "quotes"

thank you

Ivan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do:

```
awk -F\" '{print $4,$8}' file
user1 data1(none)
```

---

If number of data field does have variation and the location does vary, you can use this `gnu awk` (gnu due to RS)

```
awk -v RS="[a-z]*=" -F\" '{$1=$1} a~/^(name|trunk)/{print a $2}{a=RT}' file
name=user1
trunk=data1(none)
```

Comment: Or with cut: `cut -d \" --output-delimiter=" " -f4,8 file`

Answer (score 2):

For complete XML processing you should use [XSL Transformations](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt) with [xsltproc](http://xmlsoft.org/XSLT/xsltproc2.html) for example. The XSL file (say `user.xsl`) would be:

```
<stylesheet xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform' version='1.0'>
  <output method='text'/>
  <template match='/'>
    <apply-templates select='//user'/>
  </template>
  <template match='user'>
    <value-of select='@name'/>
    <text> </text>
    <value-of select='@trunk'/>
    <text>&#10;</text>
  </template>
</stylesheet>
```

You would then use:

```
xsltproc user.xsl my.log
```

Comment: +1 : it's better to use tools which are optimized to parse XML streams (xmllint, xmlstarlet, xsltproc or more powerfull shell languages)

Comment: @IdrissNeumann i think it's a log file , so no problem with sed or grep.

Comment: @AvinashRaj : It depends on the format of the log : if it's a well-formed XML, don't hesitate to parse it with the right tools ;) (I don't blame other solutions because of the limited information on the format of the log we have).

Answer (score 0):

Through sed,

```
$ sed 's/.*name=\"\([^"]*\).*trunk=\"\([^"]*\).*/\1 \2/g' file
user1 data1(none)
```

And the one through grep,

```
$ grep -oP '(?<=name=\")[^"]*|(?<=trunk=\")[^"]*' file | paste -d' ' - -
user1 data1(none)
```

The above commands will get the value of name and trunk fields.

Comment: @Jotne it's a log file. I think there is no problem with that. And also for simple tasks `sed` or `awk` work .